# Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler::rewind()

Tags: php, symfony, yii2, domcrawler

I was using the [Yii2 DynamicForms extension](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform)  to create dynamic fields without problems, but today when I run composer update i'm receiving the following error:

`Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler::rewind()`

The error is pointing to the line 201 of `/vendor/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform/DynamicFormWidget.php`:

```php
private function removeItems($content)
{
    $document = new \DOMDocument('1.0', \Yii::$app->charset);
    $crawler = new Crawler();
    $crawler->addHTMLContent($content, \Yii::$app->charset);
    $root = $document->appendChild($document->createElement('_root'));
    $crawler->rewind(); // Error here
    $root->appendChild($document->importNode($crawler->current(), true));
    $domxpath = new \DOMXPath($document);
    $crawlerInverse = $domxpath->query(CssSelector::toXPath($this->widgetItem));

    foreach ($crawlerInverse as $elementToRemove) {
        $parent = $elementToRemove->parentNode;
        $parent->removeChild($elementToRemove);
    }

    $crawler->clear();
    $crawler->add($document);
    return $crawler->filter('body')->eq(0)->html();
}
```

This method was removed from DomCrawler?
How to solve this?

Comment: Why don't you file a bug at the bundle?

Comment: Hi. Because the creator is no longer maintaining the extension.

Comment: You have something else going on.  The Crawler is a Symfony component as evidenced by your error message.  Crawler extends SplObjectStorage which implements the rewind method.  What version of Symfony 2 do you upgrade to?  Maybe check vendor/symfony/.../Crawler just to be sure nothing mysterious happened.  I suppose you could even check the extension just in case the author did something really crazy like replace the crawler completely.  But it all seems quite strange.

Comment: Thank you Gerad.  The new version of Crawler no longer extends the PHP SplObjectStorage.  So I turned to the old version (2.8).

Comment: @jflizandro i am having same problem but its strange that for me extension is working fine in frontend but when i coped same code to backend its throwing this error. How to change the version of crawler?

Comment: @ Mike Ross You can simply change the version of yii2-dynamicform in composer.json from "*" to "dev-master".

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is to get the DomCrawler back to version 2.8.

```js
{
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8",
    "symfony/css-selector": "2.8",
    "wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform": "2.0.1"
}
```

Taken from:
https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform/issues/108

Comment: Where do this code need to be paste? Even im facing same problem.

Comment: put on `composer.json`